# How can I use this string replace in MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, replace

I'm using Wordpress and have a load of custom fields where I need to do a string replace on. Basically I have a price field which is in the example format:
    from 113.800

I need to remove the word 'from', the space after it and the dot between the number. All the fields are in this format, how can I use a MySQL replace function to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REPLACE() doesn't support regular expression matching, so you'll have to do it in a more clumsy way:

```
UPDATE wp_sometable
SET price_field = REPLACE(REPLACE(price_field, 'from ', ''), '.', '');
```